# How to change the label alignment of the pie chart in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, pie-chart

I have created a pie chart in Visual Studio and the chart looks like this.
I would like to position the labels along the circumference of the pie chart rather than in the middle.

[image]

Any idea on how I can go about doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio is a programming environment that supports many different languages and APIs, so you need to say what charting tools and framework you are using (e.g. WPF/Windows Forms/ASP.NET).

Comment: See [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251658%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)